# How to extract test name in Google Test's case method?

Tags: googletest

I've a bunch of test cases in which each case would output a file. I'd like each files would be named after the corresponding case name so the result files won't get in the way with each other. Is there any way to do that by programming?

What I have now (hate to repeat the case name since it could be changed:

```
TEST_F(Foo, Bar)
{
  ...
  std::ofstream("Bar.bat");
  ...
}
```

What I want:

```
TEST_F(Foo, Bar)
{
  ...
  std::ofstream(magic_method_to_get_case_name() + ".dat");
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google test: Can I query the name of the test fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130122/google-test-can-i-query-the-name-of-the-test-fixture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out how to do that. I'll share it here in case anyone would like to know it.

Looks like GTEST_TEST_ macro would keep the name information in a private static variable:

```
#define GTEST_TEST_(test_case_name, test_name, parent_class, parent_id)\
class GTEST_TEST_CLASS_NAME_(test_case_name, test_name) : public parent_class {\
 public:\
  GTEST_TEST_CLASS_NAME_(test_case_name, test_name)() {}\
 private:\
  virtual void TestBody();\
  static ::testing::TestInfo* const test_info_;\
  GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_(\
      GTEST_TEST_CLASS_NAME_(test_case_name, test_name));\
};\
```

So, the code in any case could get the case name through it:

```
test_info_->name()
```

Case name is not the only information that could be fetched -- please check the TestInfo class in gtest.h.

Answer (score 3):

The current test's name can be accessed via the [`UnitTest`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#UnitTest) singleton class.

```cpp
::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->current_test_info()->name();
```

Because `UnitTest` is a singleton, this can be called from static/global test utility methods as well.