# How to get the prefix string from a INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P?

Tags: googletest

So I can see that I can launch multiple lists to be processed by my ::testing::WithParamInterface based test class, eg

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Test, TestMyDevices,  ::testing::ValuesIn(testDeviceNames))
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Real, TestMyDevices,  ::testing::ValuesIn(realDeviceNames))
```

But the prefix name of the list, eg "Test" or "Real", would be very useful information, and I don't see how to access it?

That way, for example I could have all Real devices skip internally if the real physical device interface was not available, but let our lighter-weight sham devices still be tested.

I can see that various functions and objects get created to support INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P, but I can't see how any of that information is accessible to the test class itself. I don't see those either...

Clearly, the full test name "Test/TestMyDevices.TestLatency/highError", or an address of the INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P instance would work at a pinch, but clearly the actual prefix text would be preferable.

I have stared at these impenetrable hybrid macros and template classes for far too long with no enlightenment, so all suggestions that help me keep my sanity would be appreciated.

I know I could fix it by repeating the prefix name, or some flag, in the ::testing::ValuesIn list, but repeating myself always seems like a poor solution.

Any ideas from the collective conscious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google test: Can I query the name of the test fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130122/google-test-can-i-query-the-name-of-the-test-fixture)

Comment: @273K Looks very interesting thanks!